# Select if array contains an element of another array

Tags: mysql, arrays, select, set-intersection

I have a table which has a `JSON` type field where I save a number array like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I want to select records in which its array set contains at least one element of another array I have in a php script.

I know that the `JSON_CONTAINS` function can be used to see if my array contains an element, but how can I select if both arrays has at least a common number (no matter in what index).

For example:

```
[1, 2, 3] and [5, 0, 2] -> True
[9, 2, 1] and [0, 5, 3] -> False
[4, 0, 2] and [4, 2, 6] -> True
```

---

Currently, Im using multiple `JSON_CONTAINS` to check if there are common elements, this way:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(ar, 0, '$') OR 
      JSON_CONTAINS(ar, 1, '$') OR 
      JSON_CONTAINS(ar, 2, '$')
```

But I guess there may be a more elegant way of doing this.

I searched but couldn't find the appropiate function, but if this is a dupe, let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,5,7]");
+---------------------------------------+
| JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,5,7]") |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+
```